# Did Youtube take down Dr. Pierre Kory's congressional testimony?

Tags: covid-19, social-media, censorship

Bret Weinstein claimed in an [interview on Triggernometry](https://youtu.be/sbyIIprV9pE?t=3850):

> They also removed Pierre Cory's congressional testimony. He testified
> in front of the [US] Senate on the very same topic and YouTube removed
> it. [Interviewer: "What!?"] This is absolutely factual he testified on this topic and
> YouTube removed it.

Did Youtube take down Dr. Pierre Kory's congressional testimony about how he treats his COVID-19 patients?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, YouTube removed in February of 2021 a US Senate testimony video of Dr Pierre Kory given December 8, 2020, that largely argues *Ivermectin* as a treatment for COVID-19. The [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgOAaLmoa68) now displays:

> This video has been removed for violating YouTube's Community Guidelines.
> Learn more

This "learn more" leads to [Google's COVID-19 medical misinformation policy](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9891785?hl=en&ref_topic=9282436), which is presumably the cited reason for the censorship:

> Don’t post content on YouTube if it includes any of the following:
>
> Treatment misinformation:
>
> [...] Claims that Ivermectin or Hydroxychloroquine are effective treatments for COVID-19

As evidenced by Senator Ron Johnson on his webpage "[Youtube Censored Me](https://www.ronjohnson.senate.gov/2021/1/youtube-censored-me)":

> [image]
>
> The censors at YouTube have decided for all of us that the American public shouldn't be able to hear what senators heard. Apparently they are smarter than medical doctors who have devoted their lives to science and use their skills to save lives. They have decided there is only one medical viewpoint allowed, and it is the viewpoint dictated by government agencies. Government-sanctioned censorship of ideas and speech should frighten us all.
>
> Read my full piece on this Big Tech censorship in the [Wall Street Journal: YouTube Cancels the U.S. Senate](https://www.wsj.com/articles/youtube-cancels-the-u-s-senate-11612288061)
>
> Note: YouTube gave us 5 hours warning before deleting Dr. Kory's testimony from my YouTube channel. A few days later the video of that same testimony was also taken down from Fox News Now's YouTube channel, where it had nearly 8 million views. We've seen the video on other YouTube channels like [Bloomberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8RyV3VEDKI) and [PBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxEDU3BoRm8). The question remains, why selectively delete Dr. Kory's testimony?

Evidently, the [8 minute and 42 second](https://archive.fo/lcux4) video is still to be found on YouTube, included in various long videos on other channels.
The apparent arbitrariness of the selective censorship left many curious:

> Kory he was "unsurprised" [sic] by YouTube's recent actions since he was "already made aware of that testimony video being taken down from numerous other people’s Youtube channels," but questioned the timing.
>
> […]
>
> "Why this week? After two months of it accumulating a massive amount of views?" Kory wondered.
>
> A spokesperson for YouTube defended its actions, stating "We enforce our Community Guidelines considently, [sic] regardless of speaker and without regard to political viewpoints. In accordance with our COVID-19 misinformation policy, we removed the two videos in question."
>
> — Joseph A. Wulfsohn: ["Physician slams YouTube's 'extremely misguided' decision to pull Senate testimony about COVID treatment
> Dr. Pierre Kory testified to lawmakers in December about promising COVID treatment ivermectin"](https://www.foxnews.com/media/dr-pierre-kory-youtube-ivermectin-covid-treatment), BIG TECH BACKLASH Published February 9, Fox News, 2021.

The FLCCC issued a statement called "FLCCC Response to Senate Testimony Removed by YouTube" ([PDF](https://covid19criticalcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/FLCCC-Alliance-Response-to-Dr.-Korys-Senate-Testimony-Removed-by-YouTube.pdf))

If anyone is interested in precisely what Kory said in his testimony before the committee, it is also available in written form from the US Senate website, with additional 'evidence' in the form of references he used to base his statements on: [Testimony of Pierre Kory, MD — Homeland Security Committee Meeting: Focus on Early Treatment of COVID-19 December 8, 2020](https://www.hsgac.senate.gov/imo/media/doc/Testimony-Kory-2020-12-08.pdf)

Comment: How is it "government sanctioned censorship"? Youtube is a private company and can make up its own rules. its the American way.

Comment: *Who* wrote "gov sanctioned"? You downvote an answer because you disagree with a phrase a senator used, which is then *quoted* here? What should I do now? Censor the senator again and/or alter a *quote?*

Comment: The casual use of “censored” and “censorship” in the answer is somewhat loaded.

Comment: "Loaded" needs an explanation as to 'why' & 'in what way' to be useful as a comment. the word & concept is used here as in "From 1640s as 'official empowered to examine books, plays (later films, etc.) to see they are free of anything immoral or heretical.' " As the statements in the video that were censored *are* heretical to the one true religion that governs YouTube, it seems like a nice fit?

Comment: @LangLаngС: Your comment is emphasizing that the term is loaded. Can you tone down your personal opinion of YouTube's policies?

Comment: OED: "Loaded: Charged with some hidden implication"; "Censor: One who exercises official or officious supervision over morals and conduct.", "An official in some countries whose duty it is to inspect all books, journals, dramatic pieces, etc., before publication, to secure that they shall contain nothing immoral, heretical, or offensive…" Both uses of censor aren't hidden but exactly in line what YT did. Criticising word choice in that way is not much more but expressing a political opinion in itself (private company may do… etc.). It's a usage often seen, clear in meaning, applicable here?

Comment: YouTube itself describes this practice as 'community guideline', 75% of Americans use less newspeak for that: [Three-quarters of Americans think that companies “intentionally censor political viewpoints,” according to a new poll from Pew.](https://www.vox.com/recode/2020/8/19/21373960/social-media-companies-censor-political-bias-trump-pew-study); [The First Amendment has a Facebook problem. Big Tech poses an enormous challenge to free speech](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/22356339/free-speech-facebook-twitter-big-tech-first-amendment).

Comment: I find any claims that someone is trying to prevent people from hearing the testimony a bit disingenuous, since it's [right here on CPAN](https://www.c-span.org/video/?507035-1/medical-response-covid-19), and will probably be there for as long as CPAN is a thing.  Making it _harder_ to find it is certainly true.  But it's just as easy to provide a link to CPAN as it is to YouTube, so it's not like people couldn't just link to it there, instead.

Comment: @Bobson That's an accident of different deciders on different channels. The question is about *YouTube* censorship, which is clearly limited to what they control. And this is only notable because YouTube is a monolith with millions of regular users that rarely go elsewhere.

Comment: Deleted pseudo answers that pushed a particular treatment.